# What are words which stand at the very end of a sentence (like "yo" and "tomo") called?

Tags: grammar, particles

As far as I know, "yo" at the end of a sentence indicates that quite new information is contained in the sentence, "tomo" ascertains that the content expressed in the sentence is definitely true. Both are placed even behind the predicative of the sentence: sentence-yo, sentence-tomo.

Do you know other words that are used like them?

Answer (score 6):

These are called "sentence-final particles", or `[終助詞]{しゅう・じょ・し}`.  There are many particles that can be used in this way; probably more than is acceptable for the scope of questions on this site.  But some common ones are `ね` ("agreement"), `か` (question marker), [わ (see this post)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2886/78), and `な` (prohibition).

Answer (score 0):

1. As is mentioned above, sentence-final particles are the ones that connect to predicates or other sentence-final particles.
2. The ones that connect to other grammatical elements such as nouns or adverbs are called "interjection particles".

Interjection particles can also appear at the end of a sentence when the sentence is inverted or incomplete. But they are different things. For example, 'yo' as an interjection particle is out of norm in standard Japanese unlike that of sentence-final. (A minority theory treats both of them as sentence-final, but I don't see the point of that when there's some differences.)